# How should I use pm2 command for npm run dev

Tags: node.js, npm, pm2

I'm running my app using 
`sudo npm run dev` how should I use pm2 in order to run `sudo npm run dev` this command.

Comment: would you please show how your `dev` script is defined in the `package.json` file?

Comment: ` "scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon index | myscript"
  }`

Comment: @ShimonBrandsdorfer any idea?

Comment: I see you use `nodemon`, do you need `nodemon` if you use `pm2`?

Comment: You can just do `"scripts": { "dev": "NODE_ENV=development pm2 index | myscript" }'.
Please let me know if it works

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The following works for me.

```
pm2 start "npm run dev" --name myAppName
```

Your app name will be `myAppName`

You can see the logs

```
pm2 logs "myAppName"
```

Comment: You can also specify the app name with --name argument, like this:

`pm2 start "npm run dev" --name myAppName`



Then you can see logs by `pm2 logs myAppName`


Also, please don't use `sudo` until it's really necessary (in most cases, pm2 can work fine without sudo).

Answer (score 3):

Try this: `sudo pm2 start npm -- dev`

Answer (score 3):

The answer given by @zenny is correct,  I want to add that

`pm2 start "npm run dev" --name myAppName`

try running the above command logged in as a root user instead of a non-root user. I had the same error in AWS ubuntu, it worked me.

Answer (score 0):

In your `package.json` file, you will define the scripts for npm to run.

So, you can change your file to look something like this:

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "pm2 start app.js"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Also: `pm2 start npm -- run dev`

(I didn't need to use the app name bits)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @zenny answer use the -i flag to set number of processes of the same application to spawn

```
pm2 start "npm run dev" --name myAppName -i max
```

the above command spwans max processes based on the threads of the CPU so you get a 4 core VPS or instance it will spawn 4 processes of the application.

you can use numbers to limit the process count as well, like in the command below pm2 will spawn 2 processed of the application.

```
pm2 start "npm run dev" --name myAppName -i 2
```